# MDX Navigate between hierarchies

Tags: navigation, calendar, mdx, hierarchy, fiscal

If I select [Date].[Calendar].[Day].&[2014-01-01] is it possible to navigate in MDX to the same date but in Fiscal hierarchy - [Date].[Fiscal].[Day].&[2014-01-01]?
The idea is to have option to return fiscal calculated field which would work with both fiscal and calendar dates.

Answer (score 0):

Note sure to understand exactly what you mean and if you're editing the query manually but you might have a look to the [ParallelPeriod](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/ParallelPeriod.php) function that allwos for the kind of navigation you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do a filter on the 2nd hierarchy and return the member that matches your criteria.

```
Filter( [Date].[Fiscal].[Day].Members, [Date].Fiscal.CurrentMember.Name = [Date].[Calendar].[Day].&[2014-01-01].Name).Item(0)
```

return the member you need.